# Is it possible to changes foreach php structure?

Tags: php, foreach

Is it possible to changes this foreach php structure ?

```
function token($word)
{
    $result = $word;
    $listconjunctions = ['and', 'on', 'in', 'or', 'which'];

    foreach ($listconjuctions as $conjunctions){
        $result = str_replace($conjunctions,'',$result);
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: How about `return preg_replace('|', '/'. implode($listconjunctions) .'/', '', $word);` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ask `Is it possible to changes this foreach php structure`, and yes there is no need for it

```
function token($word, array $listconjunctions=['and', 'on', 'in', 'or', 'which'])
{
   return str_replace($listconjunctions,'',$word);
}
```

There I fixed it for you, and I added the ability to give it an array of words to remove in the `$word` string.  For example:

```
$string = "this that and the other which.";
echo token($string, ['that','the','this']);
```

outputs

```
and other which.
```

I tested it with this code, just to show they are functionally equivalent, by default.

```
function token($word)
{
    $result = $word;
    $listconjunctions = ['and', 'on', 'in', 'or', 'which'];

    foreach ($listconjunctions as $conjunctions){
        $result = str_replace($conjunctions,'',$result);
    }
    return $result;
}

function token2($word, $listconjunctions=['and', 'on', 'in', 'or', 'which'])
{
   return str_replace($listconjunctions,'',$word);
}

$string = "this that and the other which.";

echo token($string)."\n\n";
echo token2($string)."\n\n";
```

Output

```
this that the other .

this that the other .
```

Try it yourself

https://3v4l.org/K83CL

**Additionally**

The problem with your original one, besides being over bloated is this:

```
$listconjunctions
$listconjuctions
```

See the difference, your missing an `n` in the one used in the foreach.

**More Advanced**
This is a much more advanced version using Regular expressions and `preg_replace`.  Regular expressions or Regex for short, is almost like another language itself.  What it does is let you pattern match in strings.

```
 function token1($word, array $listconjunctions=['and', 'on', 'in', 'or', 'which'])
{
    //escape words for use in regular expressions
    $listconjunctions = array_map('preg_quote', $listconjunctions);

    $pattern = [
        '~\b('.implode('|',$listconjunctions).')\b~i', //words
        '~\s{2,}~',  //run on spaces, 2 or more. eg. 'one    two'
        '~\s+([^\w$])~' //spaces before punctuation. eg.  'word .'
    ];

    return preg_replace($pattern, [' ', ' ', '$1'], $word);
}

$string = "this that and on and on the other which.";

echo token($string)."\n\n";
echo token1($string);
```

I named it `token1` and when running it against either your original, or my slimmed down version, we get these differing outputs.

```
 //original functionality
 this that    the other .

 //advanced version
 this that the other.
```

So as you can see the second one removes all that improper spaces. The `[^\w$]` is a character group (or a set of characters) the `[^` makes it negative and the `\w` matches `0-9a-za-Z_` and the `$` just a dollar sign.  So this means Match anything but (not) `0-9a-za-Z_$`. So what it does match are all the special characters and punctuation.

I mention this because the `$` is in there to account for things like this string.

```
'this $5.00 is what you owe me for fixing your code.' //just kidding ... lol
```

Which **would** become this without saying not to match it.

```
 'this$5.00 is what you owe me for fixing your code.'
```

You may need to add other stuff in there if you have problems like that. Just I couldn't think of any other punctuation that should be preceded by a space all the time, although I am sure there must be some.

I saw that "defect" in the original and I wouldn't feel right if I ignored it.

I hope that makes sense.

https://3v4l.org/XhOlQ

Cheers.

Comment: Ah sorry, I missed an n. Thanks for the answer and yes it works! I'm really a beginner in PHP. It helps me a lot.

Comment: I have one more fix to finish, sometimes it will return things like this `word  word` or `word .` extra spaces.

Comment: Ah, I see, thanks for your explain. But could you help me with one more chase?

Comment: I would recommend posting them as another question.

Comment: @Ncs - Ok I am all done with it, that should work in most cases.